# PL/SQL_procedure to raise emp salary has errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

The question is to write a block of codes that for those employees with a salary less than 1100, raise those people's salary by 50.

My code is as below but has error:

> ERROR at line 2: Encountered the symbol "RAISE_SALARY" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; immediate The symbol "; was inserted before "RAISE_SALARY" to continue.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure raise_salary
AS
    CURSOR c1 IS    
        select ename, sal from emp
        where sal <1100
        order by sal ASC;   
BEGIN
    FOR emp_rec IN c1 
    LOOP
        UPDATE emp
        SET sal = sal + 50;
    END LOOP;
END;
/

begin
    execute raise_salary;
end;
/
```

Comment: Remove `execute`. You call procedures using just their names and parameters, no extra keywords required.

Comment: btw there don't appear to be any errors in your procedure, as suggested in the question title. The issue appears to be about how to call a procedure. You would have hit the same thing if the procedure call was `dbms_output.put_line('Hello, world');`. Also code snippets are intended for HTML and JavaScript, not PL/SQL.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!!  I reran the code and removed the execute but still got error mesg from command saying                                                                                   ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'JL.PRINT_VALUES' is invalid and failed re-validation
ORA-06512: at "JL.RAISE_SALARY", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 2

Comment: The new error message is surely self-explanatory. The update cannot be completed because there is an invalid trigger on the table. Fix the trigger.

Comment: So after I dropped the invalid trigger, the procedure updated all emp's salary by 150. It's supposed to only update those sal <1100 by 50.

Comment: Off course it did, your update statement does not have an where clause, so it will update everything on the table every time it runs. The update and the cursor are independent of each other running an update inside a cursor doesn't mean that it will only run for that line in the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Search a little further, I think you'll find that the procedure didn't update the salary by 150, but actually updated by 50 the number of times equal to the number of rows returned in the cursor. In this case 3 rows (so 3 * 50 = 150) for anyone you validate. Further, it updated all salaries not only the ones in the cursor.

The update statement does not contain a WHERE clause, thus every row in the table is updated.

Further a simple update statement will accomplish what you need:

Update emp 
  set sal = sal + 50
where sal < 1100;

Get into the habit of thinking in terms of sets instead individual rows.